# rewrite rule for several pages to one page

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need a Rewrite Rule for the following pages:

```
/blog/2015/09/05/name-of-page.html
/old-category-name/name-of-page/
/old-category-name/name-of-page
```

All need to redirect to /new-category-name/name-of-page/

But,there might also be file names such as 
/old-category-name/name-of-page-two which would redirect to /new-category-name/name-of-page-two/

I came up with the following regex:

```
(\blog\/\[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/|old-category-name)\/\/name-of-file(\.html|\.htm|\/|\s)
```

It is working in Regex Pal, but the following redirect does not work in my htaccess file:

```
Rewrite Rule (\blog\/\[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/|old-category-name)\/\/name-of-file(\.html|\.htm|\/|\s) http://example.com/new-category-name/name-of-file/
```

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your regex and overall syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:blog/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{4}|old-category-name)/(name-of-page)(?:\.html|/)?$ /new-category-name/$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, just saw your comment tonight and will be out of the office tomorrow. I will try this out and leave my comments on Saturday Thank you!

Comment: I revised yours a bit

Comment: Ooops... Sorry it took me so long to get back to this! I revised yours a bit to escape the forward slash before the page name and revised the last bit to (?:\.html|\/|\s). I think you just missed those.  It WORKS!! :-)